# mailto with subject stopped working on android

Tags: android, html-email

So I had this working for a like 2 years now but today someone notified me it wasn't working anymore. Maybe an Android email client update?!?

```
<a href="mailto:user@server.com?subject=mysubject" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

This appears in an email and will trigger upon click a new email with the To prefilled and the subject prefilled. That is what it is doing everywhere else. It is pretty standard for as far as I can remember but now the "?subject=..." part is being appended to the email address!

Anyone had this problem?

I have tried on 2 Android device with 4.2.?? On Gmail client at least. I haven't tried on other email clients.

Wee just found a related issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63538

Comment: Is this still a bug or issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and it was probably for different reasons than what you were experiencing but I thought it might be useful to someone else. In my case lowercasing the the param Subject fixed it.